# How to stop encoding of query params value when we have some special characters in Apache Camel toD uri

Tags: apache-camel, stack-overflow, camel-rest, xml-dsl, camel-routes

```
<toD Uri="{{url}}&amp;parameterA=${header.parameterA}&amp;parameterB=${header.parameterB}" />
```

When I have slash(/) in my header.parameterA value it is getting encoded into %252F

Apache camel version used - 3.2.0.x

Can someone help me in how to stop this and pass it as slash(/) itself.

Comment: There's a lot of missing information - what the code is, what version of Camel you're running, what version of Java you're running it on...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want Camel to apply URI encoding, then you can use the `RAW(value)` syntax. For example:

```
<to uri="ftp:user@server.com?password=RAW(my/pass!or#)/>
```

There's more information in the documentation:

https://camel.apache.org/manual/faq/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html#HowdoIconfigureendpoints-Configuringparametervaluesusingrawvalues